# Change order of columns in Flask-Admin list view

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

I have a Flask-Admin list view (ModelView) of my user model with some fields excluded, custom headers, etc. Everything's working correctly and I've overridden the default list template so I can match the styling of the rest of the application.

However, my foreign key columns appear at the beginning of the list, and I need to move them around so the table makes a bit more sense.

How do I specify what order the columns appear in? Is this possible, or do I just need to add some nasty conditionals in my list template?

Comment: column_list = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'organisation', 'active', 'credit_balance', 'debit_balance'].

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Define the [column_list](http://flask-admin.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/mod_model/#flask_admin.model.BaseModelView.column_list). You define which columns appear and their order.

Example:

```
column_list = ['id', 'name', 'other_column']
```